# Power shell Script execution from the AD starup scripts

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have written a very short power shell script, that will download and install the ossec agent's binaries from locally hosted HTTP server and execute it on the respective machines. The binaries are named with respective machines IP address. I want to execute this script on more than 500 hundred machines from my active directory as a start up script but it is not working. 
I have tested the script directory from power shell on 5-6 machines and it is working. Can some one please review what am doing wrong ? Here is the simple powershell script.

```
$user=$env:username
$localIpAddress=((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://192.168.10.220/$localIpAddress.exe','C:\Users\$user\Downloads\ossec.exe')" 
cd  "C:\Users\$user\Downloads"
 .\ossec.exe /S
```

Comment: Please do not re-post questions. If you need to provide additional information: edit the question you already posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your ExecutionPolicy settings and possibly see if the file needs "unblocking" - see [here](http://powershellprimer.com/html/0010.html#10_4_4) for more info.

On a different note, using WMI is a slightly cleaner way of getting your machine's IP address, e.g.:

```
[String] $strIP = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled = "true"' | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress;
```